# Camel Case and case insensitive

Tags: plsql, case-insensitive, camelcasing

I would like your opinion about using Upper or lowerCamelCase in a case insensitive and procedural language (Oracle PL/SQL).
Some guys wanna use this pattern in my job, but the programmers don't like the idea...
Oracle Forms and Reports do not support autocomplete.

My opinion: I don't see any reason to use Camel Case in a case insensitive language...

What's your opinion?

Comment: I usually stick to UPPER CASE for system objects/names and lower case for user objects. Whatever is the convention, following it uniformly  makes it easier to read the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CamelCase really increases readability for variables when you need multi-word names, and its easier to write than using underscores for spaces, especially for programmers who use them all the time in most common languages.

in the long run, being case insensitive should free people to use whatever case they prefer, so not sure why this is an issue, but I vote Yes for CamelCase. SQL Keywords should probably be all caps or all lower, depending on your shop standard.